# Tutorial about using Spring security for authorization

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring security, so I don't know how to get it setup and configured in my web application. Does anyone know of a good reference that explains the basics of Spring security and describes common usage scenarios? Ideally I'd like to find a tutorial that describes:

- setup and configuration for authentication and authorization
- using Hibernate to fetch authorities
- required dependencies

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329660/basics-of-spring-security/67331836#67331836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html

Sections 2.1 to 2.2.4 should have everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentioned above is pretty decent, but I've also found a tough time getting decent examples online.

In the end, me and a colleague of mine ended up getting [this book: Spring Security 3](http://www.springsecuritybook.com/), and we're glad we did.  He has some good walk-throughs--the kind that seem to be lacking online.

Other than that, I think the best place to look is at code samples.  [Here's a link for the security samples on springsource.org](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/trees/master/samples).  The 'contacts' sample is a decent place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the plug for my book :) I am disappointed that I didn't have the ability to cover a JPA/Hibernate based custom Spring Security implementation in the book, so unfortunately this aspect of the poster's question wouldn't be covered.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine suggested [**5 min spring security**](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/07/07/5-minute-guide-to-spring-security/) blog link by the author of the Spring security book

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other great suggestions by posters, one online tutorial that I have seen that people like is the one at [Heraclitus on Software](http://heraclitusonsoftware.wordpress.com/software-development/spring/simple-web-application-with-spring-security-specification/) - he/she has a 16 part tutorial complete with screen shots etc. Unfortunately it covers only Spring Sec 2.0, but many of the customization concepts will be similar in Spring Sec 3.0.

[krams915](http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html) (a member of the Spring Security forums) also has a series of tutorials that he/she publishes on a regular basis, including some Spring Security 3 ones.

FWIW this question seems very similar to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641385/i-there-any-spring-security-tutorial-like-spring-step-by-step); there are many other links off of that question.

Answer (score 0):

Read:

[Basics of Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329660/basics-of-spring-security/67331836#67331836)

I have tried to explain the details to the very basics.